# MySQL JOINs - No results

Tags: mysql, join

I'm pretty sure it has to do with my order of select tables or joins, but having tried all sorts of re-ordering in my query, I'm still stuck with 0 results.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Exhibit A (returns 355 results):**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    person.person_id as "Person ID",
    CONCAT(person.last, ', ', person.first) as "Patient Name",
    person.birthday as "Birthday",
    person_ins_tie.insurance_id as "Insurance ID",
    insurance.carrier as "Carrier",
    insurance.phone as "Carrier Phone Number"
FROM
    person
        JOIN
    person_ins_tie ON person.person_id = person_ins_tie.person_id
        JOIN
    insurance ON person_ins_tie.insurance_id = insurance.insurance_id
WHERE
    insurance.carrier LIKE 'Blue%'
```

**Exhibit B (returns 0 results/no errors):**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    person.person_id as 'Person ID',
    patient.display_id as 'Chart #',
    CONCAT(person.last, ', ', person.first) as 'Patient Name',
    person.birthday as 'Birthday',
    insurance.insurance_id as 'Insurance ID',
    insurance.carrier as 'Carrier',
    insurance.phone as 'Carrier Phone Number'
FROM
    person
        JOIN
    person_ins_tie ON person.person_id = person_ins_tie.person_id
        JOIN
    insurance ON person_ins_tie.insurance_id = insurance.insurance_id
        JOIN
    patient ON person.person_id = patient.person_id
WHERE
    insurance.carrier LIKE 'Blue%'
```

I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Have you checked that there is a matching `person_id` in `patient` for any of the `person`s in the first query?

Comment: Based on this, I can't say much but check if you have good data in all mentioned tables (especially patient, since it's the difference) and check for columns you listed (do all of them exist in corresponding tables).

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` means `INNER JOIN`.

In this case when you join with `patient` table, it tries to find `person_id` from `person` table in `person_id` of `patient` table. So the only possibility here is that the `person_id` from the previous join set is not being found in the `patient` table's `person_id` column. So 0 records!